# php on submit show alert and not load action link

Tags: javascript, forms

please help , I still dont understand , could you pls change whats needed , here is my full code :

```
<form action='https://api.website.co.za/blabla?' method="get" target="POPUPW" onSubmit="alert('Done'); " >

<div align="center"><br />

<input name="user" type="hidden" value="user" />
<input name="pass" type="hidden" value="password" />
<input name="account" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$username" ?>" />


Topup Amount : 
<select name="amount" size="1">
  <option value="">  select...  </option>
  <option value="1">1GB</option>
  <option value="2">2GB</option>
  <option value="3">3GB</option>
  <option value="4">4GB</option>
  <option value="5">5GB</option>
  <option value="6">6GB</option>
  <option value="7">7GB</option>
  <option value="8">8GB</option>
  <option value="9">9GB</option>
  <option value="10">10GB</option>
  <option value="11">11GB</option>
  <option value="12">12GB</option>
  <option value="13">13GB</option>
  <option value="14">14GB</option>
  <option value="15">15GB</option>
  <option value="16">16GB</option>
  <option value="17">17GB</option>
  <option value="18">18GB</option>
  <option value="19">19GB</option>
  <option value="20">20GB</option>

</select>


<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit in Popup">
</form>
```

I have a form with an api link as form action and method is get....basically it takes info from form and gets the values entered and then adding it to the end of my api link in form action.

Now I am trying to get it to only show an alert once you click  submit and not also load the api link page ,any ideas?

at the moment it shows the alert but also loads the api link in a new page which i do not want , it should still submit that api link BUT only show the alert.

Thanks Guys :)

Comment: target="POPUPW" tells it to open in a new window.

Comment: use JS and AJAX.. only way

Answer (score 2):

this should do it... (untested)

With a little help of jQuery:

```
<form id="myform" action='https://api.website.co.za/blabla/?' method="get">
[...]
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr('action') + $(this).serialize(), function(result){
         alert('DONE');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is probably the best method, as it will alert when the submission is actually completed.

Comment: shouldnt I specify somewhere in the form to use the javascript?
bcoz it doesnt seem to work

Comment: if you added the ID to the form, the trigger will fire when you submit the form.

Comment: i have done so  , BUT alert does not popup and the action url loads in same page

Comment: then the trigger is not working... pastebin the whole code and leave a comment with the link

Comment: @user2080473 your code is missing jQuery, you should add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` before your `<script>`

Comment: ofc thanks  , that helps!!! ...one more thing.....it still does not show the alert , also want it to refresh the current page as well...

Comment: one more thing.....it still does not show the alert , also want it to refresh the current page as well.

Comment: Correction Rufinus     $.get($(this).attr('action') + $(this).serialize());
alert("done")

Comment: was no need for function(result){

Comment: then you will never know if your call was successfull, as the $.get is asyncron your alert() will fire as soon as you click the link.

with the callback it fires when the post has finished

Answer (score 1):

Add an ajax call in the onsubmit, then add `return false;` to prevent postback.

```
<form action='https://api.website.co.za/blabla/?' method="get" target="POPUPW" onSubmit="yourAjaxMethod(); alert('Done'); return false;" >
```

By using ajax, you can submit form data without having to postback.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Submit through ajax and add `e.preventDefault();` after `alert()`, like this:

```
<form action='https://api.website.co.za/blabla/?' method="get" target="POPUPW">

<script>
    $('form').submit(function() {
        //Send from using an Ajax call
        e.preventDefault();    
    });
```

Comment: same... this prevents the form from submit... see the question: "it should still submit that api link BUT only show the alert."

Comment: wow thanks for the quick response.
by adding return false; ....it semms to work BUT the api link actions does not work properly.
basically , this api action link geths hte users name from the form and the adds it to the end of the API link , by doing so when loading that link it adds a topup amount to this users dsl account via the API.
so maybe let it load page but do a redirect?

Comment: //Send from using an Ajax call

sorry very new to this...no idea how ajax js works , more detail if possible pls
Thanks again

Comment: @user2080473 The solution proposed by Rufinus seems pretty good, just add `return false;` after the `alert()` function

Comment: @uby you should always use e.preventDefault() instead of an return false. (i updated my answer)

Comment: @Rufinus You're right, otherwise propagation would stop. Corrected, thanks

Comment: one more thing.....it still does not show the alert , also want it to refresh the current page as well.